# How to bypass smartmontools scan at startup?

Tags: boot, lubuntu

I have smartmontools installed as a daemon on my Lubuntu 16.10 machine. I originally configured it to do regular scans, but I am now unable to boot the machine because as soon as Lubuntu boots I get a message saying "/dev/sdb1 "clean..." etc and it persists for literally hours.

How can I interrupt this and cancel the smartmontools scan at startup?

Comment: So maybe this isn't smartmontools but Lubuntu which is doing the device scanning....??? The message is "/dev/sda1 clean, nnn/nnn files, nnn/nnn sectors

Comment: Could be your disk failing...  *Make a back-up right now!*  (if you haven't already)

Comment: Smartmontools isn't presenting that message. It's probably fsck telling you that your filesystem is clean. Although, explain your hard disk configuration, as fsck is commenting on /sdb1... a little weird. Edit your question to include `cat /etc/fstab` and `lsblk`. You may have to boot into recovery mode.